# Forward media keys from Remote Desktop to the client

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, hotkeys, media-keys, keystrokes

I am working on a remote machine via Remote Desktop Client. Both host and client are Windows 10.

I have a Headset with Play\Pause button, and I play some music in a media player on the client. The button works fine when I am working on the client computer (is registered by media player and acted upon). However when Remote Desktop connection is open and in focus, the button is registered in the Remote Desktop Host.

Is there a way to forward certain keystrokes (like the media play\pause button) to the host, so that I would be able to use the headset media button while working inside Remote Desktop?

I know there is an option in remote desktop whether to forward hotkeys to the host, but I don't want to turn it off - I want some keystrokes\hotkeys to register just on the client, or, on both host and the client.

Answer (score 1):

When searching for this exact problem I found many people with the same issue but no solution. But after many attempts to solve it myself I got it to work, see: https://superuser.com/a/1705487/1668883

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1108968)

Comment: I agree but didn't think internal links could become invalid. Which details could I add without basically reposting my answer? I wanted to avoid redundancy and redirect possible further discussions to the other question, since OP's question is a duplicate.