# Configure keyboard media keys (volume up/down, play, next) to work in the computer even when I'm connected to a server using RDP (remote desktop)

Tags: windows, keyboard, remote-desktop, media-keys

I used to have a Logitech K520 keyboard. I usually work connected to a remote server using "remote desktop." With the Logitech keyboard, the media keys (like volume) work on my computer even when connected to the remote server in full screen.

I have changed my keyboard to a Corsair k68 mechanical keyboard. With this new keyboard, the media keys do not work when connected to the remote server via RDP.

Does anyone know how to configure these keys to work only for the local computer instead of the remote servers?

Comment: Do the media keys work locally (not RDP)?

Comment: Yes. But it's very difficult to change focus from RDP, use the volume button or next song button then open rdp window again.

Comment: Which media keys are you using?

Comment: Volume up, volume down, next track, play/pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: https://superuser.com/a/1705487/1668883
It's AutoHotkey based, just like [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)'s solution. Since I'm not allowed to comment yet (lack of reputation), I'll explain here why it doesn't work: The remote desktop window seems to rebind all keys every time it becomes the active window, which in turn disables AHK-bound hotkeys. To make AHK hotkeys work inside the remote desktop window, you need to toggle [`Suspend`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm) on and off after activating the window.

Comment: Thanks, Neon. Your script made exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can block the media keys from reaching RDP and do the change yourself.
You may use for that the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
which hooks the keyboard keys at a very low level.

The following example script will show how to intercept the volume media keys
to change the volume by increments of `2`.
Other media keys can also be hooked in this way.
This will disable the Volume Pop-Up Display of Windows.

```
Volume_Down::SoundSet, -2 ; Volume down key : Reduce sound volume by 2
Volume_Up::SoundSet, +2   ; Volume up key : Increase sound volume by 2
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the
green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [SoundSet](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tomorrow and let you know if it works. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I tested it. Same result, Volume up and down works only if the focus is on my computer and it does not work when I'm using RDP fullscreen. Do you know how do I block media keys from reaching RDP?

Comment: Strange, in all other cases AutoHotkey got the keys before RDP, so this script should have swallowed the volume media keys.

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with the keyboard model.